# psycopg2, pymc, theano and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: python, macos, pymc, theano, psycopg

I am unable to use `pymc` along with `psycopg2`. The following simple snippet from the tutorial:

```
import pymc as pm
with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Normal('x', mu=0., sd=1)
```

results in the following error:

> Exception: The environment variable 'DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH' does
>   not contain the '/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib' path in its
>   value. This will make Theano unable to compile c code. Update
>   'DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH' to contain the said value, this  will fix
>   this error.

I was able to fix this problem by adding:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib
```

to my shell init file `.bashrc`. **However**, and this is the part I don't understand, that line breaks `psycopg2`:

```
---> 50 from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
     51 
     52 from psycopg2._psycopg import Binary, Date, Time, Timestamp

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../libpq.5.dylib                                                                                                 
  Referenced from: /Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

How can I have `psycopg2` and `pymc` (here `theano`) live happily together?

This is on OS X with a Python 2.7.6 installation with an Python environment created with [conda](http://docs.continuum.io/conda/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The development version of Theano don't need changes to DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH. So undo the change to it and update your Theano version. From:

http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions

Run one of those 2 command depending of your need:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --install-option='--prefix=~/.local'
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

EDIT: I removed the link to an answer elsewhere and copied the answer here. Thanks

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon, because there is no guarantee that the link will always remain available. SO is intended to be a Q&A resource, not a help forum. That means it's not just about helping the individual solve a problem; answers should be self-contained so that they're useful for future searchers.

Comment: I understand that. But as the user asked the same question in two place and I had written an answer before seing this one, I don't want to duplicate my work. What should I do in that case? Don't answer? I think this would be worst then a link to the exact same answer. I agree that link in general are not reliable, but this one on google groups is more reliable then the average URL. I still would like to learn what you suggest I should do in that case. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I would suggest that if you answer on SO, you should post the complete answer on SO. If you're linking to someone else's answer, provide a summary. If you're linking to your own answer, you can just copy it over instead. There's no harm having it in two places--in fact, it's more "fault tolerant" that way--and if you wrote it, Google groups doesn't own the copyright, you do. And, FWIW, link only answers tend to get few upvotes, and often draw downvotes for that reason alone.

Comment: Good idea to just copy it. In fact, the URL was already broken. A nice lesson for me. Thanks @AdiInbar

Comment: Much better. :) +1 for that